# One section Core Data and another section NSMutableArray in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following code to attempt to have one section of a `UITableView` is linking to the Core Data Model and the other section is a simple cell with text:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   SubjectCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[SubjectCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.subject.text = @"Favourites";
   } else {
    Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.subject.text = subject.subject;
    cell.subjectColour.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subject.colour]];
   }

   return cell;
}
```

However the application crashes and I get a log output of this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal, if you use a NSFetchedResultsController without specified a sectionKeyName, you have one section returned with a index equal to 0.

In your sample you assume that :

the section index 0  is your Favourites

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.subject.text = @"Favourites";
   }
```

and section index 1 is your NSFecthedResultsController result

```
else {
    Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.subject.text = subject.subject;
    cell.subjectColour.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subject.colour]];
}
```

but you must re-create IndexPath to acces it with section index to 0

Try this :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
 }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    ....

    else {
        Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:    [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:0]
    ];
        cell.subject.text = subject.subject;
        cell.subjectColour.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", subject.colour]];
       }
```

for didSelectRowAtIndexPath you use the same pattern :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
    [self showList:subject animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 section in Core Data you must not ask for section 1 (i.e. the second section) in 
`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {
// wrong:
//  id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
//                   [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section]; 
//                                                            ^^^^^^^ will be 1
// correct:
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
                         [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    } 
    else {
        // core data is empty
        return 0;
    }
  } else {
// section 0
    return 1;
  }
 }
```

you should check if you have a section in your NSFetchedResultsController at all. If you don't have objects in core data `[0]` will lead to an out of bounds exception as well.

Since you have your core data results in your second section you can return 1 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` if you don't have any objects. Then you don't have to check for no objects in `t:numberOfRowsInSection:`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        // no objects in core data. only show first section
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and of course you have to change all indexPaths when you request something from the NSFetchedResultsController. The controller does not have any objects in section 1!

```
// wrong:
// Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// correct:
Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.row inSection:0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is going out of bound , please use below code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if (section == 1) {

    return [self.fetchedResultsController count];
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
 }
```